# How to make a function printf its output on a file or on console?

Tags: c, function, return

How to make a function printf its output on a file or on console? Being more specific, If in the main function I have two opinions: 1. printf the output on a file or 2. printf the output on console; and I have that other function which has the output, I would need to return that output to the main function, right? Or is there another way?

Comment: You might open a file in `main` and pass to your function where all the output is actually done with `fprintf`. In case of console, just pass stdout.

Comment: You also might take a look at [freopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen)

Comment: What exactly are you asking? stdout can be connected to a file, a terminal, or something completely else (pipe, socket, etc) on startup.

Comment: As ctx said, normal print can be printed in a file using ./a.out > file (considering your executable is a.out)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to NOT use `printf` but to use `fprintf` instead. Basically `printf(arg1, arg2, ...)` is the same as `fprintf(stdout, arg1, arg2, ...)`. As far as I know, `printf` will always print to the console no matter what you do, so if you want to redirect it, you will have to do it via the shell while invoking the program. In bash, it would be something like `./a.out > file.txt`. It's possible that there exist some way to redirect stdout to a file from within the program, but I suspect that it would not be a very idiomatic solution, but rather just a proof that it's theoretically possible.

Here is an example of how you can solve it with `fprintf`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE * fp;

    // If the program was invoked with an argument, treat it as a filename
    // and write the output to that file. Otherwise, write to stdout.
    if(argc == 2) fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    else          fp = stdout;

    fprintf(fp, "Hello, world!\n");
    fflush(fp); // Make sure everything gets printed.
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I excluded all error checks here. You shouldn't. You should check if `fopen` succeeded for instance. The condition in the if statement is also far from perfect. This is just a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a boolean flag, that if set then you call `fprintf` to print to the file, or else you print using `printf` (which will go to the console).

Something like

```
bool print_to_file = false;
FILE *file;

print_to_file = get_print_to_file_choice();
if (print_to_file)
    file = get_file_to_print_to();

// ...

if (print_to_file)
    fprintf(file, "some text here...\n");
else
    printf("some text here...\n");
```

---

Now the above is easy to implement, but hard to maintain. What if a string needs to be changed? Then you need to remember to change both for the `fprintf` and the `printf` calls.

So you could put this in a function, which takes the flag and file variables as arguments, together with the format string and arguments. This function could use the [varargs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) variants of the printing functions (`vfprintf` and `vprintf`) and do the condition in the function. In your main code you could then call this function instead.

Perhaps something like

```
void my_printf(bool print_to_file, FILE *file, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    if (print_to_file)
        vfprintf(file, fmt, va);
    else
        vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
}

// ...

my_printf(print_to_file, file, "Some text here...\n");
```

---

There are other solutions possible, like using `freopen` as mentioned in a comment. Or you could simply print to `stdout` (with plain `printf`) and then redirect the output in the shell or command prompt to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need **`fprintf`** instead of `printf`.

`fprintf` works almost similar to `printf` except that you pass an additional first argument to it. That argument is where your output is going to land.

1. If you want the output on a file, pass the `FILE*` pointer to your file as that argument.
2. If you want the output on the console, pass `stdout` as that argument.

For example,

```
FILE* myFile = fopen("demo.txt", "w");

int dummy = 22;

fprintf(myFile, "%d will be written in <demo.txt>", dummy);

fprintf(stdout, "%d will be written in the console", dummy);
```

**Note:**

You don't need any new header file for `fprintf`. It resides inside the regularly included `stdio.h`. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) is a complete reference for `fprintf`.